# Question migration

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

If, hypothetically speaking, I will ask a question on a SF "I plan to set up an Oracle Exadata installation at my home, [...]" - will it be forcefully migrated to the SU ?

Comment: What is your _real_ question?

Comment: My cultural level doesn't allow me to ask it, so I have to use euphemisms. But I'm sure you've got it.

Comment: No, I really do not understand what you're trying to hint at.

Answer (score 7):

Hypothetically speaking, there's no way this is an actual question, and if someone asked a question like this, with the current level of context on *SU* it would be closed. Such a question wouldn't be migrated to SF, and I wouldn't expect SF to migrate it as it stands.

"I plan to set up an Oracle Exadata installation" is a statement

"at my home" may be irrelevant.

With the information on hand, as a SU mod, If I was asked if I wanted the question, I'd go *hell* no.

That you're running it on unsupported hardware might be - but it doesn't really look like something you'd run on a couple of dozen random PCs you picked up off the curb. So assuming you went into the constraints of running this in your garage I'd recommend the following close reasons

- Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers.

*or*

- Questions should demonstrate reasonable business information technology management practices. Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault - see the help center.

I am doubtful the *average* home user, sysadmin or otherwise is likely to have a quarter rack, and *call for a quote* amount of money to spend on a storage array.

So, *If* someone voted to migrate *and* 4 people *agreed* or a mod chose to migrate such a hypothetical question, I'd throw it back over the fence.

Answer (score 0):

I will doctor your grammar and distil the question:

> If I ask a question on ServerFault about setting up Oracle Exadata at my home
>   will it be migrated to SuperUser?

Well it would be off topic, so... yes.

Comment: It would definitely be closed.  Whether or not it got migrated to SU is a question that could really only be answered with an experiment.

Comment: I'm afraid I have to down-vote our answer here. It sends a wrong message answering a question with what boils down to: *if a question is off topic it will be migrated*. I realise that isn't the intended answer, but out of context it suggests a bad precedent.

Comment: @Reaces Good point. I didn't quite catch on to that nuance.